# Is this a valid proof that $f_{x_0}:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be a metric space, and let $x_0 \in X$ be a fixed point. Show 
>   that the real function $f_{x_0}$ given by $f_{x_0}(x) = d(x,x_0)$ is a 
>   continuous function.

The definition of continuity at a fixed point $x_0 \in X$ is $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta: d(x,x_0) < \delta \implies |f_{x_0}(x) - f_{x_0}(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

I know $f$ is *continuous* if it is continuous at every point in the domain ($X$), and I know that $f$ is continuous at a point if

Let $x \in X$ be an arbitrary point.

The RHS of the implication simplifies to $|f_{x_0}(x) - f_{x_0}(x_0)| = d(x,x_0)-d(x_0,x_0) = d(x,x_0) < \epsilon$.

So if $\delta = \epsilon$ the implication holds, and because we chose an arbitrary $x \in X$, $f$ is continuous everywhere
.

Comment: You need choose an arbitrary x and see $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta: d(x,y) < \delta \implies |f_{x_0}(x) - f_{x_0}(y)| < \epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this proof works for $x=x_0$.

But you **only** show continuity at $x_0$ but you need to do it for all $x$, so show the full non-contractiveness:

$$ \forall x, x' \in X: |f_{x_0}(x) - f_{x_0}(x')| \le d(x,x')$$

using the triangle inequality. Then $\delta=\varepsilon$ will still do.

Comment: Would this work? Let $\epsilon$ be given, and let $x,x' \in X$. To show $f_{x_0}$ is continuous we need to find $\delta: d(x,x') < \delta \implies |f_{x_0}(x)-f_{x_0}(x')| < \epsilon$. RHS simplifies to $|d(x,x_0)-d(x',x_0)| \leq d(x,x')$ (by the reverse triangle inequality). Because $|f_{x_0}(x)-f_{x_0}(x')| \leq d(x,x')$ and $|f_{x_0}(x)-f_{x_0}(x')| < \epsilon$, $d(x,x') < \epsilon$. Then let $\delta = \epsilon$.

Comment: @MatthewRiley No, the last sentence is the other way round : because $d(x,x') < \delta$, we know that $|f_{x_0}(x') - f_{x_0}(x)| \le d(x,x') < \delta=\epsilon$.